# Cannot open R installed through Brew

Tags: r, homebrew

I'm new to R, and I tried installing R through Brew by entering

`brew install r`

brew automatically installs all the dependent formulas (I think?) so I didn't go through installing gcc or gfortran (which seems obsolete from brew?)

The problem I'm facing is that I cannot start R in terminal

i tried typing `r` like how I would start other programs, no luck. I got

`-bash: r: command not found`

I then checked the path for the installation and found that it's inside `/usr/local/cellar`, okay, expected, but I still have problem opening it.

I read online and found that many have the link problem, which I faced as well when `brew link r`

I got

```
Linking /usr/local/Cellar/r/3.2.2_1... 
Error: Could not symlink .
/usr/local/Library/LinkedKegs is not writable.
```

I'm not sure if that's an issue.

I remember seeing someone using R and it seems a lot like Matlab/Pandas where you get an interactive GUI (or some sort) that you can instantly see the output once entering the command.

What am I missing here? How do I get it to start?

Thank you.

Comment: https://cran.r-project.org/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you need tap in homebrew/science

```
brew tap homebrew/science
brew install r
```

Maybe you need instal homebrew, if you not install yet.
[Example](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/121402)

Before you need set ownership LinkedKegs:

```
sudo chown -R $USER /usr/local/Library/LinkedKegs
```

Comment: hi there! I forgot to put that line in but I've done that as well

Comment: This is it! Thanks! I guess it's the permission issue